# Can't able to run perl script through post-commit.bat file

Tags: windows, perl, svn

On windows I've a perl script which will create a file & add content to that.

When I run the script it is working fine, 
and even it is working fine when I call this through `.bat` script.

**perl script:-**

```
open IN,">hello.txt";
print IN "hi";
close(IN);
```

**post-commit.bat**

```
PATH=C:\Perl64\bin
perl D:\Repositories\HooksExample\hooks\ExecuteJenkinsBuild.pl
```

But when I test this with **SVN hook "post-commit.bat"** (modifying the file and committing) file then it is not calling the perl script and not showing any error message.

Can any one please help on this?

Comment: Are you sure it's not working? If the current working directory was somewhere you didn't expect, my guess would be that the output just ends up there and you're not seeing it. Even without `use strict` and  `use warnings`, you should get an error message about output to closed file handle if there had been any error opening the file.

Comment: The script is running fine when we run it, and also when we call the perl script with batch script then also it is running fi
Since the batch script is SVN's Hook script, so this is script has to call when ever we commit the changes, but it is not running as expecting.

I'm new to hook script, should i need to add any svn commands in perl to run this script ???

Comment: I haven't used SVN hooks in more than a decade so I'm not sure but it would surprise me if you had to do anything special there. Try adding some `echo` at the end of the batch file so you are sure the hook is called correctly and the batch executes until after the perl call, and then use an absolute path instead of "hello.txt" so you don't depend on the current working directory being set to something known.